# Bash, Waiting for tor proccess circuit to be complete "Bootstrapped 100%: Done" before follow other instructions

Tags: bash

The main idea is the following:

```
###Launch tor & polipo
./launchTorPolipo.sh start 1 5
#wait the circuits to be complete
#then
./otherScriptDependingOnTorPolipoStates.sh
```

in the script `./launchTorPolipo.sh`:

```
mode=$1
minimum=$2
maximum=$3
if [ $mode = "start" ]; then
    for i in `seq $minimum  $maximum`;
    do
        tor -f /etc/tor/torrc$i &
    done
fi
...
```

as you can see above the way I launch tor instances is `tor -f /etc/tor/torrc`.

But I don't know how to automate in a bash script, to wait all the tor instances launched to be `Bootstrapped 100%: Done`.

I searched a lot about status, but it seems to be for processes running as deamon, and this is not the case of my tor instances when I look at `ps aux | grep torrc`.

- So first of all, to reach my goal, must I run the tor instances as deamon ? For instance to use `systemctl` commands ? I don't know.
- Is it even necessary to add an instruction to ask the script to wait for tor circuits to be completed or will it do this implicitly (what I doubt)?
- Are there other ways to reach it ?

Comment: I do not think that you should run tor as daemons ( background != daemon),

Answer (score -1):

Are several ways to solve this.
you can user bash built-in command wait  https://ss64.com/bash/wait.html
added at end of your script launchTorPolipo.sh

```
mode=$1
minimum=$2
maximum=$3
if [ $mode = "start" ]; then
    for i in `seq $minimum  $maximum`;
    do
        tor -f /etc/tor/torrc$i &
    done
fi
echo "waiting process to end.."
wait
echo "process ended"
```

Comment: Is wait done for a process ending ? I mean waiting for the PID to disappear.

Comment: I confirm it wait for the end of the process, when PID disappear. That's not what I am looking for at all.

Comment: ok, I see now, I this case you should detect the status from the tor process o in the logs